# Protect application from SQL injection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection

I have a big form and when I am trying to execute a SQL query to save form data, I get a `SqlException` (something like more then 1200 SQL parameters per query).

Explode query by a few queries with less then 1200 SQL parameters is not a good idea because of performance issues, and actually it is not easy to do. I am afraid put raw values in SQL query it might create security problem with SQL injection.

So what can I do? And if I put raw values what is best way to protect application from SQL injection attack?

Comment: The only reliable way: ***ALWAYS*** use **parametrized queries** and no exceptions to that rule.

Comment: There's a hack with the U+02BC unicode quote mark that gets around escaped single quotes in SQL Server (replacing one quote mark with two), but it only works if the string is implicitly cast to ascii. There are other attacks on MySQL etc that use the fact that there are multiple ways to escape the string terminator, but that's not true in SQL Server.

Comment: marc_s makes the most important point. You should also validate your inputs: most information (names, addresses, etc., etc.) doesn't contain quotes, dashes, apostrophes etc., so filter them out and let the user know

Comment: Why are you trying to pass that many parameters? Is this for a long `in` list for example? If so and you are on SQL Server 2008+ look at TVPs. If not please provide details.

Answer (score 1):

Create xml of your parameter values and pass the xml as a single parameter. Then just parse the xml into any number of variables (or rows in a temp table). For example, instead of:

```
SELECT ?, ?, ?
```

and passing in `'my first form value'`, `'my second form value'`, and `'my third form value'`, you could do:

```
DECLARE @x XML SET @x = ?;
SELECT 
    T.x.value('@a1', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
  , T.x.value('@a2', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
  , T.x.value('@a3', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
FROM @x.nodes('/form/data') AS T(x)
```

and pass just the one xml parameter, `'<form><data a1="my first form value" a2="my second form value" a3="my third form value" /></form>'`. SQL Server 2005+ has a very efficient xml parser so I would imagine this to be just as fast as passing the parameters directly.

Of course you have to take steps to generate injection-resilient xml, but this is what I would do if I had to pass so much into a query.

(That said, I'm having a hard time imagining a situation in which one might legitimately need that many flat parameters. Accepting arbitrary data rather than explicit parameters would make more sense to me, in which case the above xml might be more like `'<form><data name="a1" value="my first form value" /><data name="a2" ... </form>'`, but the same solution would still work.)